# starting a process with exactly the same address structure as previous openning

Tags: memory, ram

Is it possible to start a process in windows with exactly the same address structure as the previous opening of the process?

To clarify the goal of this question I should mention that I use cheatengine (http://www.cheatengine.org/) to cheat some games! It includes several iterations to find a parameter (e.g. ammunition) and freeze it. However, each time I restart the game, since the memory structure of the game changes, I need to go through the time-consuming iterations again. So, if there were a method bring up the game exactly with the same memory structure as before, I wouldn't need going through iterations.

Comment: Even if you get the operating system to keep everything the same, you can't prevent the process from making its own decisions that would affect the address structure. I would suggest that you learn programming by doing something other than trying to cheat at games (which is a very advanced topic).

Comment: Dear, actually this cheating is done as a commercial project in which I should extract some game parameters in order to be able to control some peripherals! Anyway, thank you for the advice:-)

Comment: In which case you can work with the game vendor to get access to what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to say it's impossible, but this is essentially too much work due to the dynamic memory allocation routines the process will be using including the new operator and malloc().  Additionally when the DLL's imported by the executable are loaded into memory they have a preferred imagebase but if that address is already used, the OS will load it into a different memory location.  Additionally Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) can be enabled on the process which is a security measure that randomizes the memory address of code sections.

The solution to your problem is much easier then what you're asking.  To defeat the dynamic memory allocation described above you can still resolve the correct address of a variable by utilizing:

- Relative offsets from module bases
- Multi-level pointers
- Pattern Scanning

Cheat Engine has all 3 of these built into it.  When you save an address to your table is often saves it as a module + relative offset.  You can pointer scan for the address and save it as a multilevel pointer or reverse the pointer yourself and manually place it in the table.  Pattern scanning is achieved by using a CE Script, which you can put right in the Cheat Table.

In this case the ammo variable, may be a "static address" which means it's relative to the base address of the module.  you may see it listed in Cheat Engine as "client.dll + 0xDEADCODE".  You simply get the base address of the module at runtime and add the relative offset.

If you're looking to make an external hack in C++ you can get started like this.

In an external hack you do this by walking a ToolHelp32Snapshot:

```
uintptr_t GetModuleBase(const wchar_t * ModuleName, DWORD ProcessId) {
    // This structure contains lots of goodies about a module
    MODULEENTRY32 ModuleEntry = { 0 };
    // Grab a snapshot of all the modules in the specified process
    HANDLE SnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, ProcessId);

    if (!SnapShot)
        return NULL;

    // You have to initialize the size, otherwise it will not work
    ModuleEntry.dwSize = sizeof(ModuleEntry);

    // Get the first module in the process
    if (!Module32First(SnapShot, &ModuleEntry))
        return NULL;

    do {
        // Check if the module name matches the one we're looking for
        if (!wcscmp(ModuleEntry.szModule, ModuleName)) {
            // If it does, close the snapshot handle and return the base address
            CloseHandle(SnapShot);
            return (DWORD)ModuleEntry.modBaseAddr;
        }
        // Grab the next module in the snapshot
    } while (Module32Next(SnapShot, &ModuleEntry));

    // We couldn't find the specified module, so return NULL
    CloseHandle(SnapShot);
    return NULL;
}
```

To get the Process ID you would do:

```
bool GetPid(const wchar_t* targetProcess, DWORD* procID)
{
    HANDLE snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (snap && snap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
        pe.dwSize = sizeof(pe);
        if (Process32First(snap, &pe))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!wcscmp(pe.szExeFile, targetProcess))
                {
                    CloseHandle(snap);
                    *procID = pe.th32ProcessID;
                    return true;
                }
            } while (Process32Next(snap, &pe));
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Using my example you would combine these functions and do:

```
DWORD procId;
GetPid(L"game.exe", &procId);
uintptr_t modBaseAddr = GetModuleBase(L"client.dll", procId);
uintptr_t ammoAddr = modBaseAddr + 0xDEADCODE;
```

If the address is not "static" you can find a pointer to it, the base address of the pointer must be static and then you just follow the above guide, and dereference each level of the pointer and add an offset.

Of course I have a function for that too :)

```
uintptr_t FindDmaAddy(HANDLE hProcHandle, uintptr_t BaseAddress, uintptr_t Offsets[], int PointerLevel)
{
    uintptr_t pointer = BaseAddress;
    uintptr_t pTemp;

    uintptr_t pointerAddr;
    for (int i = 0; i < PointerLevel; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            ReadProcessMemory(hProcHandle, (LPCVOID)pointer, &pTemp, sizeof(pTemp), NULL);
        }
        pointerAddr = pTemp + Offsets[i];

        ReadProcessMemory(hProcHandle, (LPCVOID)pointerAddr, &pTemp, sizeof(pTemp), NULL);
    }
    return pointerAddr;
}
```

I would highly recommend watching some Youtube tutorials to see how it's done, much better explained in video format.

Comment: Actually, I have done it through pattern Scanning; anyway, thank you for your thorough answer.